# Link over whole div is not working when cursor is over contained text in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have [this code for demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/DzpjT/1/). It makes my link spread over whole div, which works great in Firefox, but in IE when I move cursor over text it changes to text cursor and link doesnt work there... I tried fiddling with `z-index` but no results... any suggestions?

I need to fill my div with other divs with their own content, so

```
a style="display: block"
```

is not an option, an i also want to avoid Javascript like

```
onclick="location.href=
```

Comment: Same Question is answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438048/css-problem-link-positionabsolute-above-a-box-not-work-in-ie-opera/6438212#6438212

Comment: sory, i forgot some informations, now(after edit) its clear that solution you suggested will not work for me...

Comment: Would you be willing to switch your doctype to HTML5?

Comment: No, unfortunetly thats not an option on that project :-(

Comment: Actually I think it is possible. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a solution for you. In HTML5 it would be valid to use `<div>`'s inside of an `<a>` tag. But since you cannot change your language and HTML4.01 does not allow block elements inside of an `<a>` I would suggest *faking* it. By that I mean use `<span>`'s inside of the `<a>` tag instead and style them to act as a `<div>`. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/DzpjT/11/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <span class="fakediv">Annoying text la lallalalalalalalalal</span>
        <span class="fakediv">Annoying text la lallalalalalalalalal</span>
    </a>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
a{
    display: block;
    width:700px;
    height:500px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
span.fakediv{
    float:left;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: this is interesting idea, i will try it tomorrow and let you know, looks like you will get some points from me :-) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" style="display:block;position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left: 0; z-index: 10;"></a>
```

Should work fine now. I added display block to the anchor tag which will cause it to behave like a div.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to tell that i need to have several other divs with some content in my div, so <a> tag styled as block wouldnt be an option...

Answer (score 1):

Like brenjt said, I think you simply need to add a height attribute to your css. He threw some other stuff in there too which is all good, but in my experience it's not having height set explicitly in your CSS that often causes this.

Comment: to which element? div has height of 500px and span has 100% of that divs height

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific enough. Try changing the span height to pixels instead of a percentage.

Comment: just tried it, but this is not the case where this would help... thanks for trying though

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but since the content I was attempting to cover had heading and paragraph tags, I was hesitant to start mocking css classes up to mimick paragraphs and headings unnecessarily.

While I was debugging the issue, I added a background colour to my a tag. This clearly demonstrated that the tag was completely covering the content from just above it in the DOM, as it was supposed to. The entire area was clickable. As soon as I removed the background colour, hovering over the text converted the cursor to the insert icon and didn't register a click.

So, seeing as I was already employing a 1px transparent png on the page anyway (for fixing custom fonts in IE), I just set that as the background image on the a tag.

It works.